# How to calculate bitrate of PAL format?

Tags: video, bitrate

I have to calculate the bitrate of PAL format (576∗720). I have the following data:

1. 25 frames per second
2. Interlaced
3. Interior representation is:  4:2:0
4. 8 bpp

I have tried the following formula but I am really not sure at all if it is correct because I have not clearly understood the difference between interlaced and non-interlaced video and how this difference changes the calculation fo the bitrate.

This is what I tried:

`(576∗720)∗(1+1/4+1/4)∗8∗25`

This part:  `(1+1/4+1/4)` is due to the specific representation 4:2:0

Comment: Interlaced does not impact digital bandwidth (only analog transmission). Your calculation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your formula is correct.**

Interlace video with 50 fields per second has the same bitrate as progressive video with 25 frames per second.

Interlace video is transmitted in fields.
Each **field** contains 1/2 of the video lines of the **frame**.
PAL frame is 576 video lines, so PAL field is 288 video lines.

According to [ProVideo Coalition](https://www.provideocoalition.com/field_order/), the order of the field in PAL is "upper field first".
Size of two interlace fields equals the size of one frame:
[image: Interlace]
Remark: It's possible that the two fields are captured in separated times, and the two fields do not belong to the same frame (in 4:2:0 separate times it is unlikely).

In 4:2:0 format, the resolution of the Y component is the resolution of the frame.
The U and V components are down-sampled by a factor of 2 in each axis.
Assuming 8 bits per component, there are 12 bit per pixel in average.

- 8 bits per Y component.
- Average of 2 bits per U component (8/4 because size of U is 1/4 of size of Y).
- Average of 2 bits per V component (8/4 because size of V is 1/4 of size of Y).

Interlace or not, your formula is correct.

`bitrate = (576∗720)∗(1+1/4+1/4)∗8∗25` [bits per second].